# Eclipse platform URL throws MalformedURLException

Tags: eclipse, url, resources, malformedurlexception

The following code:

```java
URL url = new URL("platform:/resource/MyProjectName")
```

...throws this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: platform
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I have never heard of URLs beginning with `platform:`. Why did you think this would work? Is it meant to be `resource:/platform` instead of `platform:/resource`?

Comment: `platform:` is valid in an Eclipse context if you are using it in a plugin for certain purposes. So what are you doing?

Comment: yes i have a java application that should have been a plugin. i am scared to death of plugins as I have no clue how to debug them. So i made a java application. So platform:/ is invalid in java application. looks like i have to convert my java application to plugin

Comment: But what are you doing with the URL?

Comment: i want to get the absolute URL